# Launch activity/intent from Android Wear without opening ui on phone

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, wear-os

I'm building an android-app with wear-support and having the following problem when I add a notification with the voice-action specified here:

http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/voice-input.html

```
        // Create an intent for the reply action
        Intent replyIntent = new Intent(mainActivity, VoiceActivity.class);
        replyIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent replyPendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(mainActivity, 0, replyIntent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);         

        // Create the reply action and add the remote input
        NotificationCompat.Action voice_action =
                new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(R.drawable.ic_action_mic,
                        getString(R.string.label_voice), replyPendingIntent)
                        .addRemoteInput(remoteInput)
                        .build();
```

Everytime the wearable calls the voice action / pending intent(?) my activity starts in `onCreate()` and opens my MainActivity-UI on the phone! But the thing is, the user is working simultaneously on the phone and don't want to get interrupted by a simple voice-action.

**Any ideas how to pretend the voice-command from opening the app on phone when it's "minimized"?**

Comment: Than why your using the Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP flag, rather use android:launchMode="singleInstance" to make your activity single instance, or use Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag.

Comment: `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` works! Thanks a lot!!!! Write it as answer to get reputation ;-)

Comment: So why are you launching an activity if you don't want to open any UI??? It's just the opposite of what you want to achieve.

Comment: see the sample-code from google. an activity is required to open voice-control on an android wear. so if I fire this intent/activity with a wearable, it does not need to show up any information on the handheld ;)

Comment: You can use the `WearableListnerService` on the phone, as well. Non-interrupting.